# How can I divide i18n resources into several files?

Tags: internationalization, playframework

Instead of putting all the i18n resources into a single message file, I want to divide them into several files. Anybody can kindly tell me how can I do that? because the documentation of Play doesn't give me any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Messages](http://www.playframework.org/modules/messages) Module, really nice for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can't on Play. Anyway, why would you need to do that? Makes harder to find where the keys for I18N are. If it's for "visual" purposes, just use comments (##) to create sections in the file.

Comment: @Pere: Several files are much easier to maintain than one large file. Also, it works better with Translation Memory. As for finding keys, I don't quite get what you mean. Just use the right tools (like Total Commander, UltraEdit or any other that let's you search the contents of the files).

Comment: @Paweł Dyda I feel simpler to have 1 unique location for all the text, not 4 different files open in my IDE. As per Translation Memory, I don't see how it makes more complex to load the data into the system...but doesn't matter, personal tastes in the end. Play doesn't allow it, that's all :)

Comment: @Pere: Localization engineers usually don't use IDE... As for TM, it might be worse to select four files but the matching process works better and produces less strings to re-translate.
Also, when you are working in the large team when many people access the same resource file, it could be really tricky to merge your changes. It is not the taste, it is experience.
Play Framework is definitely very specific (for example forcing UTF-8 as an encoding is interesting idea).

Comment: @Paweł Dyda to be honest I never had a localization engineer in any of my teams, but now that you mention this it makes more sense. Thanks for the info! :)